# Uncheck the checkbox within the gridview template field from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to uncheck all the checkbox present in the Gridview with server side button click. I'm trying to execute the below code

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           CheckBox chkrow = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ChbGrid");
           if(chkrow.Checked)
           {
            chkrow.Checked = false; //code not reaching here eventhough checkbox is selected
           }
        }
    }
```

The chkrow.Checked is false for every row in the gridview eventhough some of the checkbox are selected. Any idea on why this might be happening ?

Comment: When does your code fragment execute? Only when the page is first rendered, or do you have a partial postback when you click the button you refer to?

Comment: Post you page_load method code

Comment: I'm another button called "Clear Selection" and on the click event of that selection it calls the above method. It loops in all the rows but the chkrow.Checked is still false on all the rows. 
on the page load, I'm calling a method called LoadGridview()

Answer (score 0):

I just got the issue fixed. It was because the button was within the updatepanel and gridview was outside the update panel